# What's the role/position of biblical God in Shuumatsu no Valkyrie?

Tags: record-of-ragnarok

In Shuumatsu no Valkyrie, gods fight humans to decide if humanity should be allowed to continue or not. In this story, you see ancient Greek gods like Hades, Zeus and Poseidon, ancient Norse gods like Thor, Loki and Odin, Hindu gods like Shiva, Japanese gods like Susanoo, and more. We also see Adam, the first human, who was created by God, the biblical God, Adam is one of the fighters for humanity.

In the Bible, the biblical God created everything, the universe, the creatures, etc. How does this work in this story? Is the biblical God supposed to have created all the other gods, or is he just another god among all the gods?

Comment: I think its worth noting the religions that believe in the God of Abraham (Christianity/Judaism/Islam) aren't the only belief systems with their own creation story. Most of the featured pantheons have their own (conflicting) mythos. How did humans come about? Did Odin, Vili and Ve craft them from tree trunks, did Prometheus craft them from clay, were they the tears of the Eye of Re, the progeny of kami, and so on and so forth. It isn't just God that would be strange to slot into a coherent world in the story

Comment: @Gatchwar About that, at least partially they have to acknowledge abrahamic religions version of the creation, because they stated Adan is the first human and ancestor of all humanity. I suppose that most likely they didnt even think about all these contradictions, but a possible solution I suppose would be making abrahamic god creating this universe, and other gods creating other universes or the multiverse.